# Use dd to back up?

Tags: disk-image

If I use dd command make an img file to back up my disk when I am using Ubuntu Live USB, and than I format my disk. Can I restore my file from that img file? (including the data is not files)

Comment: But I have aome files be remove, I want to restore them. You know, if I just copy the files, it does not work. So i want to use dd to creat a image of my disk, and then, restore them.

Comment: I don't see the point of what you are planning. If you take a `dd` copy of your disk, format it and restore the `dd` image, you will get exactly what you have now (assuming no error). So why format the disk?

Comment: What do "if i just copy the files it does not work" and "(including the data that is not files)" mean? Those could indicate a serious problem with your system that dd could *not* fix, or a serious problem with your approach. It's not clear. Please edit your original question to clarify. Please do not bury important information in comments. Comments are intended to help you improve your question.

Comment: @user535733 I accidentally deleted some files, but I was anxious to use my computer, so I used dd to back up the disk, and then use the disk recovery software to scan the obtained img file. Is this OK? (from Google Translate)